# C Struct Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Default struct given:

```
struct counter {
  long long counter;
};    

struct instruction {
  struct counter *counter;
  int repetitions;
  void(*work_fn)(long long*);
};

static void increment(long long *n){
  n++;
}
```

My line:

```
n = 2;
struct counter *ctest = NULL;

int i;
if( ctest = malloc(sizeof(struct counter)*n){
  for( i=0; i<n ;i++){
    ctest[i].counter = i;
  } 

  for( i=0; i<n ;i++){
    printf("%lld\n", ctest[i].counter);
  }
}

struct instruction itest;

itest.repetitions = 10;
itest.counter = ctest; //1. This actually points itest.counter to ctest[0] right?
                       //2. How do I actually assign a function?    

printf("%d\n", itest.repetitions);
printf("%lld\n", itest.counter.counter); // 3. How do I print the counter of ctest using itest's pointer?
```

So I am trying to get those three things working.

Thanks

Comment: It's ok, fixed most of the mistake from the help provided Thanks

Comment: P.S. @Jono It will be better to upvote usefull answers and answer you accepted:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> itest.counter = ctest; // This
>   actually points itest.counter to
>   ctest[0] right?

Right. `itest.counter == &ctest[0]`. Also, `itest.counter[0]` refers directly to the first ctest object, `itest.counter[1]` refers the 2nd, etc.

> How do I actually assign a function?

```
itest.work_fn = increment;
```

> How do I
>   print the counter of ctest using
>   itest's pointer?

```
printf("%lld\n", itest.counter->counter); // useful if itest.counter refers to only one item
printf("%lld\n", itest.counter[0].counter); // useful if itest.counter refers to an array
```

Comment: How could I pass the n in the function increment ? itest.work_fn = increment (n); ?

Comment: @Jono: You don't pass an argument at the time of assignment, but merely the address where the function code starts. You pass the argument when you call it indirectly through the pointer: `itest.work_fn(n)`.

Comment: @Jono - Note that your work function takes a *pointer to long long*, not a *long long*. So, you would invoke it: `itest.work_fn(&n);`  Also note that your `increment` function has a bug -- it modifies the local argument, but has no observable side effect. I think you meant `static void increment(long long *n){ (*n)++; }`

Answer (score 0):

1. This points to addres of ctest. (which is same as addres of it's first element)
2. You should declare some function whith same signatur (say `void f(long long *)`) and here write `itest.work_fn = f;`
3. `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) printf("%lld\n", itest.counter[i].counter);`

Comment: static void increment(long long *n){
  n++;
}
Say if I want to use this function? itest.work_fn = increment //What about the n ? how do I pass it?

Comment: You can call `itest.work_fn(n);` and this will increment your n.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. But maybe it is more clear like this:

```
iter.counter = &ctest[0];

itest.work_fn = increment;

printf("%lld\n", itest.counter->counter);
```

That is if you plan to have only one counter. From your code you want multiple and maybe you should store the number in struct instruction.
If so, then it would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < itest.n; i++)
    printf("%lld\n", itest.counter[i].counter);
```

In this case the function should also be changed.